# About conformal covering map from $S^3$ to $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds, spheres, conformal-geometry

I need to understand the properties of a conformal covering map from $S^3$ to $S^3$?

Would anybody kindly recommend me some references (both books and papers are OK).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you tag your question as [tag:reference-request]. It is more appropriate for your question than [tag:geometry].

Answer (score 1):

The thing to know is [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) which states that every conformal map $U\to S^n$, $n\ge 3$, defined on an open connected nonempty subset $U\subset S^n$ is the restriction of a unique [Moebius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Higher_dimensions) of $S^n$. You can find proofs in many places, in particular, in the references given in the linked Wikipedia article. Incidentally, even if you do not assume conformality, each covering map $S^n\to S^n$ ($n\ge 2$) is a homeomorphism, as follows from the fact that $S^n$ is simply-connected.

Comment: And to be concrete, we can view $S^n$ as the projectivized light cone of $\Bbb R^{n+1,1}$ on which ${\rm O}(n+1,1)$ acts (these are called Mobius transformations). I think this is the full conformal group, and is generated by involutions whose actions on $S^n$ under stereographic projection look like spherical inversions in $\Bbb R^n$ (compare with Cartan-Dieudonne).

Comment: @runway44: More precisely, in this model, the quotient of $O(n+1,1)$ by its center (which has order 2) is the full Moebius group. But there are other ways to define Moebius transformations, for instance, using the formula given in the link, or as compositions of inversions.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @KuigeLi: If this indeed answers your question, you should click on "accept" ("check") symbol next to the answer to indicate that this question was answered. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer